# How to append/insert text to JTextArea in equal locations in new line in loops

Tags: java, append, jtextarea

I have following problem: I create program to count a points of athletics from different school. I adds points from the same school, and try to display it in JTextArea. For example:

[image]

I'm using to it this part of code:

```
notatnik_k.append("\n" + "Miejsce:   Nazwa szkoły:   Pkt.:   Pkt. WOM:" + "\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < tab1_klas_kobiet_średnie_pkt.length; i++)
            {
                notatnik_k.append("    " + zm_miejsce1_średnie_k + "               "  + średnie_bez_duplikatów.get(i) + "             "  + tab1_klas_kobiet_średnie_pkt[i] + "             "  + tab1_klas_kobiet_średnie_pktWOM[i] + "\n");
                zm_miejsce1_średnie_k++;
            }
```

But it's not so fine. I get back uneven breaks.  I try use "insert" something like this:

```
if(i == 0)
                {
                notatnik_k.append("                                             " + "\n");
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(zm_miejsce1_pdst_k), 50);
                notatnik_k.insert(podstawówki_bez_duplikatów.get(i), 68);
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(tab1_klas_kobiet_pdst_pkt[i]), 84);
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(tab1_klas_kobiet_pdst_pktWOM[i]), 98);

                notatnik_k.append("                                             ");
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(zm_miejsce1_pdst_k), 0);  
                notatnik_k.insert(podstawówki_bez_duplikatów.get(i), 2);
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(tab1_klas_kobiet_pdst_pkt[i]), 36); 
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(tab1_klas_kobiet_pdst_pktWOM[i]), 43);
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                notatnik_k.append("\n" + "                                             ");
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(zm_miejsce1_pdst_k), 1+45*i);
                notatnik_k.insert(podstawówki_bez_duplikatów.get(i), 2+45*i );
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(tab1_klas_kobiet_pdst_pkt[i]), 36+45*i);
                notatnik_k.insert(String.valueOf(tab1_klas_kobiet_pdst_pktWOM[i]), 43+45*i);
                }
```

etc.

but it's too not good (not nice looking).

I want to get back something likie this:

```
Miejsce: Szkoła: PKt: Pkt WOM:
   1     IVLO    25   18
   2     IIILO   16   10
..............................
   20    VILO    2    1
```

Please, help.

Comment: It would be much easier to use JTable than trying to do this in JTextArea. Do you need to do this in JTextArea?

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'll check this "JTable" :), maybe I don't need in JTextArea, but when I create program I'dont think about JTable.